# Laravel 5.1 throws csrf token mismatch exception even thought csrf protection is disabled

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I have set up our login/register routes to specifically not use csrf protection. The forms do not have csrf token fields. I have told Laravel not to check these routes in the VerifyCsrfToken middleware:

```
protected $except = [
        '/login',
        '/register'
    ];

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        foreach ($this->except as $except) {
            if ($request->is($except)) {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }

        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }
```

And yet I get csrf exceptions when using these routes. Any ideas how this could happen?

EDIT: I haven't solved the problem yet, but I noticed that bypassing csrf protection works with the same code base in my local environment but not in our staging environment. It's very odd. If anyone has a theory please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the leading slashes
so instead of

```
protected $except = [
    '/login',
    '/register'
];
```

put this

```
protected $except = [
    'login',
    'register'
];
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thank you Malicoder. You are an absolute genius for noticing the obvious.